# Can Google Analytics and Google Search Console coexist if tied to different accounts?

Tags: google-analytics, google-search-console

Can Google Analytics and Google Search Console coexist without issues for the same website if the Google account that is used for Google Analytics is not the same as the account used for Google Search Console?

Context: I'm building a site for a client and would like to monitor the site's performance on google while letting him use his own analytics account. I would like to avoid any trouble with google and don't want my Google account to get banned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not an issue at all.
They are different tools and verified differently.

Info on linking together:

Each account is not tied to only one user account.

In GA you can add other users will full access at the account or property level.
In SC you can add other *owners*.

Therefore, if any of the accounts have the same user in both, you can link them together in GA.

Answer (score 0):

Should not be an issue, however you wont be able to link the two products together though, as doing so requires the same Google Account be used.